# Can't enable ellipse character on long text not fitting the cell in a table

Tags: html, css, text, ellipsis

I want an ellipsis to appear whenever the text gets cut off when the width of the table cell is too narrow to display it. According to [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/), it's supposed to look as below (nothing surprising there).

```
td {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

However, I can't make it work. First I thought it was because I'm applying Bootstrap and there might be some styling poofing my approach but then I tried to reproduce the error in an isolated fiddle and - tada! - I got it working. (I.e. I got it to **fail ellipting**, hence got the reproducible error to **succeed occurring**.)

The fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/rLxhh69k/). What am I missing?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Table cells don't handle overflow well. You will need to set the **`max-width`** CSS property on each td for the overflow to work. Try to make use of **`max-width`** instead of **`width`**

> [*The max-width CSS property sets the maximum width of an element.
>   It prevents the used value of the width property from becoming larger
>   than the value specified by max-width.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

td {
  background-color: pink;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Alias</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Updated</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Ali Baba &amp; Co.</td>
      <td>Boys 'n da hood</td>
      <td>Somewhere over the rainbow</td>
      <td>February 30th</td>
      <td>Do stuff!</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Solution 2**

Or Just place the **`td`** content inside **`<span>`** and then apply the css

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

span {
  background-color: pink;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Alias</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Updated</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Ali Baba &amp; Co.</span></td>
      <td><span>Boys 'n da hood</span></td>
      <td><span>Somewhere over the rainbow</span></td>
      <td><span>February 30th</span></td>
      <td><span>Do stuff!</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Must I explicitly add *max-width* to the style? I was hoping that, in the end, I could rely on Booty setting it for me as a part of my styling of the whole table control with *class=table"*. My reason for asking is that I want the table to occupy full width of the screen so *max-width* creates another issue.

Comment: @DonkeyBanana Table cells don't handle overflow well. you will need to set the max-width CSS property on each td for the overflow to work

Comment: @DonkeyBanana Or you can wrap the `td` content in `span` and then apply css as mentioned solution2 above

Comment: I noticed an interesting thing. As I mentioned, I want my table to occupy the whole width, so I have to make the cells percentual not fix-width. When I set *width:100%* to each div (I skipped span with block display), it doesn't work **but** if I set *width: 99%*, it does ellipsing. WTF?!

Comment: The question has been resolve so I'm accepting the answer. However, I'd love you to elaborate on the weird thing I mentioned in the comment above. That'd make me +1 happy, hehe.

Comment: @DonkeyBanana If you are applying width 100% in table and td inner div then you have to apply `table-layout:fixed` to table. Check the updated Solution2!